# Dynamically allocate an array of strings

Tags: arrays, c, string, dynamic-memory-allocation

How can I fix this code in a way that it prints the words in the array? Moreover this is the right way to dynamically allocate memory for `n` words of max size 40?

```
int main() {

    int n;
    char *arr;
    int i;

    printf("Give me a number:");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    arr = malloc(n * 40);

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        printf("Give me a word: ");
        scanf("%s", &arr[i]);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        printf("%s", arr[i]); //< --problem here
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: No, `char`s and strings are not the same.

Comment: Try for example `typedef char BUF[40];` then `BUF *arr = malloc(n * sizeof(BUF));`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your allocation is not the best, and `printf` argument `arr[i]` expects a `char*` but you pass it an `int` (a `char` if you'd like).

Here is how you should do it, with comments:

[Live demo](https://onlinegdb.com/rygPmmjGw)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> //for malloc

int main(){
    int n;
    int i;
    
    printf("Give me a number:");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    //declare a variable of pointer to pointer to char
    //allocate memory for the array of pointers to char, 
    //each one capable of pointing to a char array
    char **arr = malloc(n * sizeof *arr);

    if(arr == NULL){ //check for allocation errors
        perror("malloc");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    //allocate memory for each individual char array
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++){
        arr[i] = malloc(40); //char size is always 1 byte

        if(arr == NULL){ //check for allocation errors
            perror("malloc");
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
    }

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++){
        printf("Give me a word: ");
        //limit the size of read input to 39 charaters to avoid overflow, 
        //a nul character will be added by scanf
        scanf("%39s", arr[i]);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++){
        printf("%s\n", arr[i]);
       
    }
     
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){ //free the memory for each char array
        free(arr[i]);
    }
    free(arr); //free array of pointers

    return 0;
}
```

You can also do this with less code using a pointer to array of 40 chars, this will simplify the memory allocation and deallocation:

Sample with comments:

[Live demo](https://onlinegdb.com/Hy5gNQizD)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> //for malloc

int main(){
    int n;    
    int i;

    printf("Give me a number:");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    //declare a pointer to array of chars and
    //allocate memory for all the char arrays
    char (*arr)[40] = malloc(n * sizeof *arr);

    if(arr == NULL){ //check for allocation errors
        perror("malloc");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++){
        printf("Give me a word: ");
        scanf("%39s", arr[i]);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++){
        printf("%s\n", arr[i]);
    }

    free(arr); //free allocated memory

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: In his code `&arr[i]` was a `char*`, since `arr` is `char*`, `arr[i]` would be `char` and adding an ampersand makes a pointer to a value.

Comment: Nitpick: Since the allocation is 40 chars to each string, I would prefer the more simple allocation: `char (*a)[40]; a = malloc(n * sizeof *a);` Then both `malloc` and `free` are one-liners.

Comment: @cajomar, yes, you're right, I read it diagonally didn't pay attention.

Comment: Thank you but why i can allocate also as @4386427 said? In this way the allocation isn't only for one string? I understand better the first code, can you explain me better  how the second one allocate memory for all n words and not for only a single one as i think? How can i read this: "char (*arr)[40]"? And what's the difference with "char *arr [40]"?

Comment: @Boninissimo, it's a bit more crypric but it's +- easy to understand, `arr` is a pointer to an array of 40 chars as such `sizeof *arr` (the dereferenced pointer ) is 40 bytes in size, this multiplied by `n` will give you the block of memory you need, now as `arr` is a pointer to 40 chars, incrementing it will make it point to the next block of 40 chars. For example if `n` is 2 you'll have a block of 40 * 2 bytes, `arr[0]` points to the beginning of the block the 1st byte, if you will, `arr[1]` jumps 40 bytes and points to the second "line", byte 41. This is stored in memory in a linear way.

Answer (score 1):

This:

```c
for(i=0;i<n;i++){
    printf("Give me a word: ");
    scanf("%s",&arr[i]);
}
```

is probably not what you want.
You probably want this instead:

```c
for(i=0; i<n; i++){
    printf("Give me a word: ");
    scanf("%s", arr + i*40);
}
```

then later:

```
for(i=0; i<n; i++){
    printf("%s", arr + i*40);
}
```

Remember that a string in C is just an array of characters.
Thus when defining `char *arr`, you are creating a *single string*. Had you done `char **arr` it would have been an *array of strings*, which is what you want.
However, I find that allocating/freeing arrays of arrays on the heap to be rather inconvenient, and prefer 'flattening' them into a single array.
This is exactly what you were doing with `arr = malloc(n*40)`, but then later you treated this array of *characters* as an array of *strings* when you did this:

```
for(i=0; i<n; i++){
    printf("Give me a word: ");
    scanf("%s", &arr[i]);
}
```

Note that this is actually perfectly legal (`scanf` wanted a `char*` and you gave it one), but it's a logical error since you are giving it the `n`-th *character* when you wanted to give it the `n`-th *array*.

And oh yes, don't forget to `free(arr)` later.